# I need to install tensorflow 1.x and the code works until last week on google colab. Now it does not work

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I need to install **TensorFlow 1.x** for solving my problem. When I run the below codes a week back on google colab **(python version 3.8)**. It installed successfully, and since then I haven't changed anything on my code. However, now, when I run the same code a week later, it does not work,

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

It shows the below error.
[image]

Alternatively, I tried to change the **Python version to 3.6.9** by using the below command,

```
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!apt-get install python3-pip
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

After that I can install tensorflow 1.14. But then it says to restart the runtime. When I restart the runtime, it cannot connect anymore. It always shows **connecting**, below is the error view,

[image]

I do not know what changes of google colab cause this issue. Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a same error. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: `Tensorflow 1.x` is no longer supported in `Google Colab` and deprecated to use since `Aug 1, 2022`. It is recommended to use the latest versions of tensorflow in the `Tensorflow 2.x` series. Please check this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#migrate-from-tensorflow-1x-to-tensorflow-2) to convert your `TF 1.x` code to run in `TF 2.x`.